# In eclipse Map/Reduce location, New Hadoop location not responding?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-plugins

In eclipse I am trying to add new hadoop location. But when I click for adding new hadoop location, it is not responding. I build my own plugin for hadoop 1.0.4.

My Manifest looks like below,

```
Bundle-ClassPath: classes/,
lib/hadoop-core.jar,
lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar,
lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar,
lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar,
lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar,
lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar,
lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
```

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm using hadoop 0.21.0. Btw, have you fixed the issue ? What is the manifest ? Thanks :D

Comment: The hadoop-eclipse-plugin.*.jar when you extract will have a manifest file.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the jar package but the problem persists. Have you fixed yours ?

Comment: Also you have add some this jar in build.xml also.check out at the end of build.xml. all this jar are included in xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here in Chinese but you can use google translate or just download the file: http://yizhilong28.iteye.com/blog/1030536.